# How Cocos2d and other 2d OpenGL Engines draw sprites?

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0, theory

Just for learning purpose I want to build a really simple 2D openGL Engine, so I'm really curious to understand how the most famous Engines work (or at least which is your idea).

I know that using a SpriteBatches the engine performs a single drawing call per SpriteBatch while drawing simple sprites every sprite needs a drawing call. 
Let's say that I'm only interested in drawing separated sprites without a SpriteBatch.

**Here is my idea for simple Sprites drawing:**
I suppose they are represented through a plane and a texture. Every plane has a set of vertices and indices and a common shader (let's keep it simple). 
The sprites are stored in a sort of array and **for each sprites** the engine needs to set a `VBO` with the vertices of the current plane and call `glBindBuffer`, `glBufferData`, set the shaders and call `glDrawElements`. 
The VBO is then cleared and the previous operations are repeated for the next sprite.

**Could it be a common routine to draw sprites?**

**About the SpriteBatch** I suppose that the big difference is that the VBO stores the vertices of every plane once and for this reason it is able to draw all the sprites in a single `glDrawElements` call.

**Am I on the right way or my "suppositions" are totally wrong?**

Comment: Actually cannot understand, why you can't just see cocos2d sources. It is an open-source framework, so it is not a big trouble to find how it draws sprites. About batching there is one thing that you missed in your description. All sprites in case of batching must use the same texture. So you bind one texture (it can be huge spritesheet), and store all of your sprites vertices to draw in a single array. That's why they draws with the single call.

Comment: @Morion ... lol, you cant say it enough. Read the code Luke, read the code ... especially for NSAsserts. Should almost be in the FAQ.

Comment: @Morion err.. I tried, but it is not really simple to understand how it works. Many classes and a few comments. I'm new in OpenGL and I'm working at this custom engine as exercise.

Comment: Anyway... this tutorial could be a useful resource: http://www.verend.com/openglindex0.html

Comment: don't just read the code, step through it to experience the flow and how it changes values. Every function you don't know, look it up to learn what it does. Take things out too, to see if it breaks, and how.